# Wordpress : add_action not working in plugin or functions.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got two functions:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' , 'after_order_complete' , 10);
 function after_order_complete( $order_id )
 {
   error_log("woocommerce_order_status_completed", 0);
 }

 add_action( 'wp_login', 'after_login', 10, 2);
 function after_login( $user_login, $user ) {
   error_log("wp_login", 0);
 }
```

that I can't seem to get called, tried in a plugin and functions.php but they never fire and no errors are logged.

How is it I debug this to find out why they fail or does anyone know how to get these to work?

In the same code I have another add_action but this time using user_register and that works as expected from plugin or functions.php

Edit:

I have the wp_login figured out, action does get called but only when first visiting the back end, site is front end only for users so used membership system hook instead.

Comment: on which page you are testing about actions ?

Comment: I test the functions in a plugin and in functions.php, the actions hooked are when a user logs in and when a user buys something.

Comment: Did you try to send mail with **error_log** function ? or die() function ?

Comment: No but I did try using add_user_meta / update_user_meta and they fail.

Comment: Try to die("some string") and check if it dies or not.

Comment: die("test") seems to do nothing.

Comment: Maybe there is a hook in your `functions.php` file which somehow disables this functionality. Try to add this function at the very beginning of the `functions.php` file and test it then.

Comment: I tried that but never worked then went to do it in a plugin thinking the plugin would be loaded before the functions.php

Comment: `die` and `error_log` are both triggered. Do you have anything suppressing errors? Try disabling all other plugins and switch to a default theme.

Comment: helgatheviking, tried all that but still nothing but this works though woocommerce_payment_complete, what's the difference between that and woocommerce_order_status_completed?